# MongoDB getBoolean returns null

Tags: java, mongodb

I have been trying to get a boolean value off of a collection in MongoDB, but when asked through getBoolean, I receive null.

In the MongoDB document there is 1 with the following information:
name:"Test"
booleanValue:true

```java
Document searchQuery = new Document();
searchQuery.put("name", "Test");
FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find(searchQuery);
for (Document document: documents) {
    String name = searchQuery.getString("name");
    Boolean booleanValue = searchQuery.getBoolean("booleanValue");
        System.out.println(document);
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(booleanValue);
}
```

It shows that it can find the document and the name as it prints everything, even get the booleanValue right, but when I getBoolean I receive null.

Document{{name=Test, booleanValue=true}}
Test
null

Comment: you are trying to get from `searchQuery`, not from the `document` returned from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document searchQuery = new Document();
```

You have created the `Document` here. It does nto have any key called `booleanValue`.

```
Boolean booleanValue = searchQuery.getBoolean("booleanValue");
```

Now you're trying to query that object here. Of course you won't find anything for the key `booelanValue`. You probably mistook the `searchQuery` for the result documents.

```
for (Document document: documents) {
    String name = searchQuery.getString("name");
    Boolean booleanValue = document.getBoolean("booleanValue");
        System.out.println(document);
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(booleanValue);
}
```

You need to query `document` instead.